# Does 1-phenyl-1-keto-but-2-ene show positive iodoform test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

> It is told often that only compounds having a methyl ketone and corresponding alcohols show positive iodoform test.

I tried to sketch a mechanism to show that 1-phenyl-1-keto-but-2-ene also gives iodoform test. However I haven't found any source that confirms that 1-phenyl-1-keto-but-2-ene shows iodoform test.
Please check if there is any mistake in the mechanism:

[image: My proposed mechanism]

This mechanism is very similar to the classical iodoform reaction mechanism.

Comment: C-C double bond group not have larger -Ieffect as compared to C=O group and abstraction of H+ from C H bond is not so easy by OH-. This fact can be used here.

Comment: However the carbanion at gama position is stabilized by resonance.

Comment: Why space between keto and but?

Answer (score 5):

Enones react with with iodine and catalytic base under aqueous conditions to give $\alpha$-iodoenones (Ref.1). Pyridines are most often used for this, the reference quoted also uses $\ce{K2CO3/DMAP}$. They further show that reaction works for a range of enones including those with the $\ce{RCOCH=CH-CH3}$ grouping and no mention is made of $\gamma$-iodination. A "background" reaction was run with $\ce{K2CO3/I2}$ in aq. THF and no iodination was observed.

Proposed mechanism from the referenced paper:

[image]

---

**References:**

1. Marie E. Krafft, John W. Cran, "A Convenient Protocol for the α-Iodination of α,β-Unsaturated Carbonyl Compounds with $\ce{I2}$ in an Aqueous Medium," *Synlett* **2005**, *(8)*, 1263-1266 (DOI: 10.1055/s-2005-868495).

Comment: @waylander the document in your link requires paid subscription. Could you please provide the link of some other source which shows the reaction?

Comment: I got to it directly through Google Scholar by searching "alpha iodination of enones" The paper is by Krafft and Cran and is the top hit on the Google Scholar

Comment: Thanks, I saw the reaction. But is there any reaction reported using OH- and I2

Comment: The closest is the K2CO3 in aq THF without added pyridine which gives no reaction, I think that is a significant result with respect to your question. I would expect I2/OH- to similarly give no reaction